# show checkboxes in 2 columns in Flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, checkbox, flex3, repeater

I am using Flex3 and a newbie to it.
I am using repeater to create checkboxes.
I don't want to align all checkboxes vertically because there are a lot of them.
I want to show checkboxes in 2 columns to save some space?
I can do some magic to x and y properties.
But is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to wrap a pair of CheckBoxes in an HBox and repeat that.  Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable]
        private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([1, 2, 3, 4]);
        [Bindable]
        private var checkBoxLabels:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                                                    "Red",   "Blue",
                                                    "Green", "Yellow",
                                                    "Purple","Brown",
                                                    "Gray",  "Black"]);
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Repeater id="myRep" dataProvider="{dp}">
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:CheckBox label="{checkBoxLabels[myRep.currentIndex*2]}"/>
                <mx:CheckBox label="{checkBoxLabels[myRep.currentIndex*2+1]}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:Repeater>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```